# JavaScript delete text in every 3rd line in a txt document

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

I need a little help to automate a task.

**Before.txt**

01 ABCDE
02 ABCDE
03 ABCDE
04 ABCDE
05 ABCDE
06 ABCDE
07 ABCDE
08 ABCDE
09 ABCDE

**After.txt**
01 ABCDE
02 ABCDE
03
04 ABCDE
05 ABCDE
06
07 ABCDE
08 ABCDE
09

Comment: So what did you attempt?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: It's much easier to think to come up with an idea than to post a question right away. Basic concept: Read the file line by line. Accept only initial characters on every third iteration(using a counter, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `words` by your string. `result` is the final string with all it's values joined together by a new line.

```
var words = "01 ABCDE\n02 ABCDE\n03 ABCDE\n04 ABCDE\n05 ABCDE\n06 ABCDE\n07 ABCDE\n08 ABCDE\n09 ABCDE";

// we split the file into an array using the new lines as the split point
var lines = words.split(/\r?\n/);

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  // we take every third line and delete all the chars from 3 and beyond
  if (i > 0 && i % 3 === 0)
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, 2);
}
// we join the values again
result = lines.join('\n')
```